# How to get category ID from get_query_var

Tags: wordpress, variables, loops

How to get category ID from the query?

For example I have following URL:

```
http://localhost/website/[some-custom-tax]/[category]
```

Basically, I want to list all post for given `category` in archive.php

Comment: Wordpress creates taxonomy archives automatically. You don't need to get the ID or do anything specific, just use the loop as always.

Comment: Hmm, it is listing all posts for all categories. So something must be wrong with my archive.php

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you haven't altered the query. You may test it again by using the default index page template of wordpress and you should get only the posts of your category.

```
    while (have_posts()) :
       the_post();
       the_content();
    endwhile;

    endif;

    get_sidebar();
    get_footer(); 
?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action